# Best way to notify the moderators?

Tags: discussion, flagging, spam-handling

So in the wake of the UFC-spam attack last night, I (like many of you) used-up all of my flags trying to fight the onslaught of crap being posted on our site.  At one point, I noticed my flag amount getting low, but I kept seeing new spam questions coming in, and wasn't sure if I was really making any difference.

I then thought that we need to get the moderators involved here, but I was unsure how to do that.  After all, a flag is supposed to notify the moderators.  I briefly checked the chat rooms, but I didn't see anyone I recognized.

Perhaps a flag threshold is necessary?  Such as, whenever so many users log a certain number of flags within a 10 minute time period, the mods or even some of the SE folks are automatically notified?  Although, anyone monitoring the web traffic on AskUbuntu last night should have picked-up on the fact that we were getting hammered.

Is there something additional that I/we should have or could have done?

Comment: We are spread across several timezones. Chat messages & flags are generally a good way.

Comment: Immediately after reading this question title - @Mods ping came to my mind. If curious, have a look at this related Meta Post - [An atModerators ping](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126988/an-moderators-ping/)